# How to check if a tuple value exists in a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a column in a DataFrame which contains either strings or tuples of strings. I would like to check whether a certain tuple of values is present in that column.

```py
s = pd.Series(['a', ('b', 'c', 'd')])

'a' in s.values
```

This returns `True`. However:

```py
('b', 'c', 'd') in s.values
```

returns `False`, with a warning: `FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison`.

How can I work around this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `x in y` is short-hand for a `for` loop. You can just do `any(x==('b','c','d') for x in s)`.

Comment: Seems to be an oddity with the ragged array of nested sequences that numpy doesn't like. You can use the list instead: `('b', 'c', 'd') in s.tolist()`

Comment: Using `s.tolist()` is clearly the best and simplest option. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
s = pd.Series(['a', ('b', 'c', 'd')])
def check_tuple(x, tuple_string="('b', 'c', 'd')"):
    if str(x).find(tuple_string)>=0:
        return True
s.apply(check_tuple)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all hash values of objects in your serie, and compare it to the hash value you looking for